# Open Sourced PDF Reader

Tags: java, c++, pdf, open-source, pdf-reader

I am currently working on a project that requires me to display PDF documents to the user amongst other things.

**Is there a free and open sourced PDF Reader that I can customize and build my project on top off?**

A Java code base would be perfect, though, C/C++ will do as well. The reader does not necessarily need to be very fancy, but it should be able to handle displaying PDF files completely by itself. Also, I would prefer if the software license allows code customization of a proprietary nature.

**If no such PDF Readers exist, is there a PDF library that I can leverage, that will handle/help in *displaying* the PDF content besides parsing it?**

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just open the PDF file in an external program, i.e. use the one already in the system?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - Would I be able to grab the PDF text being displayed currently, from the external program?

Comment: A firefox project (https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) which might interest you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suns PDR-Renderer and Multivalent are both Open source and there are OS versions of JPedal and Icepdf.

Comment: PDF renderer looks good, though it does not offer PDF text extraction by default. I found this paper (http://www.iaeng.org/publication/IMECS2011/IMECS2011_pp283-286.pdf) and customized the library a little according to the Upgrade Study section. Thanks everyone for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest investigating MuPDF. Its open source, but you need to be GPL-compliant to use it that way, however it can also be commercially licenced.

Answer (score 0):

As for a free library, have a look at [poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/).